# Exception in switch case

Tags: php

In my class's method I declared a `switch` which return specific values. If user add other value, it would display exception. **Objects will be created in the loop**. If, only type is other than in switch, it should display an exception.

I implemented exception but I don't have idea where can I add try...catch or what can I do next. I don't have idea that my idea is well but goal is the most important for me.

```php
class Example {
    private $name;
    private $type;

    function __construct($name, $type)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $this->mySwitch($type);
    }

    private function mySwitch($type)
    {
            switch($type){
                case 'first':
                    return 'first';
                break;
                case 'second':
                    return 'second';
                break;
                default: 
                    throw new Exception("Oooops");
                break;
            }
        }
    public function getText()
    {
       return 'Hello' . $this->name . ' ' . $this->type;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no loop in the question and also having problems to understand what your concern is, you might benefit from improving the question, in its current form I'd say it lacks clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `try{}` and `catch{}` blocks where you use the method. So in your constructor, where you have `$this->type = $this->mySwitch($type);`, you could do:

```php
function __construct($name, $type){
    $this->name = $name;

    try {
        $this->type = $this->mySwitch($type);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->type = 'value_in_case_of_oops';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but in this case you set $this->tape. Look at getText(). I  want to display exception instead of this text. It first. Second - if I will create object in the loop, I want that this exeptation will be display only one, and if only one object run the exceptation.

Comment: Whatever you want to do when the exception happens, you can do in the catch block. If you want to show an error and stop everything, replace what's inside the catch block by `echo "your message here"; die();`, for example.